Looking for movie title of brunette woman raped by male coworker and gets flashback of getting gang-raped when younger
I'm looking for the title of a movie I saw in July of 2011, not sure if it got released that year but definitely either 2011 or before.
Opening scenes of the movie include:

A young teenage girl walking through a "field-like" property and is approached by a couple of men and is thrown to the ground and gang raped.
That initial rape scene also acts a flashback scene because that same young girl that got raped is raped again in a corporate building where she works by one of her male co-workers many years later (as an adult and the actress who plays the adult who got raped has brown hair). 
Not sure as to whether the rape is the main premise of the movie, but from what I remember there seems to be many stories happening at once and the main male actor of the movie is this blond, white male who plays a businessman of a company (the company where the girl got raped by one of the coworkers). 
He has a heavy accent while speaking english, not a british accent though so it was hard to tell what accent it was exactly. 
The genre of the movie was definitely dark,a lot of rape is portrayed,  it was also business-oriented and included issues about some of the business opportunities happening within the company. 
The male (he has brown hair) who rapes the woman is in cahoots with the main blond male businessman (as mentioned above).
I believe the movie is independent and not produced in Hollywood. Most of the actors have heavy accents when speaking English.also, I do not believe the movie was set in America.
From the accents and appearances of the actors; my best bet would be that the movie took place in a European country such as Sweden. 

If I recall, the title of the movie was pretty long (it wasn't just one name).
